# list of strings can not be converted to gson.JsonElement

Tags: java, string, jsonelement

I have want to create a jsonObject in java of this type:

```
"a": "b",
"c": {
  "d": {
    "e": [
      "f",
      "g",
      "h"
    ]
  }
}
```

Following is a snippet of the code where I try to add the value of "e" given in the form of the list:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add("f");
arr.add("g");
arr.add("h");
JsonObject arrayList = new JsonObject();
arrayList.add("e", arr);
```

In this portion I am getting an error:

java.util.List<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to com.google.gson.JsonElement

Any suggestion to resolve this issue will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
arrayList.add("e", gson.toJsonTree(arr));
```

Comment: Thanks Saad. Now that line compiles. However, in the next line I am getting the error: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Thanks Saad. Now that line compiles.  However, I have the following as well: JsonArray arrayJson Json = new JsonArray(); arrayJson.add("d", arrayList). Here I am getting the error reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length. Don't know why ?

Comment: JsonObject dObj = new JsonObject();
dObj.add("d", arrayList);
System.out.println(dObj);

Comment: Thanks Saad. That works. But let's say if I have like "a": "b",
"c": {
  "d": {
    "e": [
      "f",
      "g",
      "h"
    ]
   "i" : [
      "j",
      "k",
      "l",
    ] 
  }
}

then should I use an JsonArray and how ?

Comment: You can create and put the "e" and "i" object into a list and add that list to "d"

Comment: Thanks Saad. My bad. Wanted to ask about a slighlty different structure. Cen you help me with the following structure.
"a": "b",
"c": {
  "d": {
    "e": [
      "f",
      "g",
      "h"
    ]
    },
    {
   "i" : [
      "j",
      "k",
      "l"
    ]
    } 
  }
}

Should I still use a list or an array ?

Answer (score 0):

This compiled and ran without error for me:

```
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add("f");
arr.add("g");
arr.add("h");
JsonObject arrayList = new JsonObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();
arrayList.add("e", gson.toJsonTree(arr));
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. Now that line compiles.  However, I have the following as well: JsonArray arrayJson Json = new JsonArray(); arrayJson.add("d", arrayList). Here I am getting the error reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length. Don't know why ?

Comment: @CodingPractice - If you can edit your original post and then post your complete class so I can see what you're trying to do that would help. But here is the class definition for a JsonArray and you see exactly what you are allowed to pass into the array. https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html